# Enhanced auth dialog on iOS doesn't complete login flow

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app that uses the Facebook SDK for authorization.  The existing app does not ask for manage_actions permission.  I'm using fairly standard code to start the login flow:

```
NSArray permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", @"publish_stream", @"user_education_history", @"rsvp_event",@"user_events,user_interests", nil];
[self.model.facebook authorize:permissions];
```

When I enable the enhanced auth dialog in the FBDev App and then try to sign into my app, I see a new mobile auth dialog prompting me to Add to Timeline.  However, clicking the button on this screen does nothing.  It doesn't show an error and doesn't return to my app.

Are there any known issues or workarounds for this flow using the new auth dialog?
(Saw this on an iPad with iOS 4.3)

Thanks,

Edit: One more detail, I saw this using the Facebook app for sign in, I haven't tried it using Safari.

Comment: Any ideas?  It is the Facebook app getting stuck, not my app.  But if the enhanced auth dialog gets turned on for everyone on Monday, this completely blocks users from logging into my app.  When I click the "Log in" button, the page flickers, but it does not switch back to my app like the old auth dialog did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been caused because I didn't have the Bundle ID set through the DevApp.

After setting the iOS Bundle ID in the Settings -> Basic -> Native iOS App section of the DevApp, I have stopped being blocked by the Enhanced Auth Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In `Facebook.m` you have this method: `- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth`. You can try setting both `tryFBAuth` and `trySafariAuth` to `NO` at the beginning of the method.